# Regex - how to match 'ß' to 'ss' and vice versa

Tags: c#, regex, localization, cultureinfo

Folks, how can I do a regex match on a *sharp-s* character (`ß`) with `ss`, and vice versa? I tried the invariant culture, but it doesn't return a match. However, if I use `String.IndexOf()` with the invariant culture, it *is* able to.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("abcßßdefßßghi".IndexOf("ssss", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >=0);

var matches = Regex.Matches("abcßßdefßßghi", "ssss", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);

// OUTPUT
True
0
```

I need to find all of the indices where the match starts. The idea is to highlight the 'matched' string. I'm looking for a clean approach with `Regex.Match()`, which is preferable to iterating over the string and substring and so on. TIA.

Comment: For the purpose of search engine optimization, the sharp-s character (`ß`, `ẞ`) is also known as a Eszett. For those not familiar with the _sharp-s_ character, it is pronounced similar to `ss` and the two are used interchangably in written German—and thus the need to be able to treat them as synonymous when parsing a string. (`ß` is technically more correct, but not all typefaces support it.)

Comment: Interesting question. And, I'm embarrassed to admit, I can think of at least three cases where I've written localization code where I didn't account for this. Out of curiosity, does this work if you explicitly set the culture to `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, and the current `CultureInfo` is set to e.g. `de-DE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get over this scenario, I ended up replacing `ß|ss` with `(ß|ss)` in the search term and then doing a lookup for it

```
var cleanSearchTerm = Regex.Replace(Regex.Escape(RemoveDiacritics(searchTerm)), "ß|ss", "(ß|ss)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var matches = Regex.Matches(RemoveDiacritics(item), cleanSearchTerm, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
```

this would give matches for `ß` and `ss` in a search term containing `ß` and/or `ss`

Comment: This is basically the same answer I provided a month prior. In the future, please just accept the existing answer instead of reposting the core guidance as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the answer you were hoping for, but after looking into this for a bit, there doesn't appear to be a solution which relies on the `RegexOptions`. Even explicitly setting the `CurrentCulture` to `de-DE` and removing the `RegexOptions.CultureInvariant` yields incorrect results. Since this works with `IndexOf()`, I'd consider this a bug in the `Regex` library.

Given that, the best workaround is likely to explicitly handle both scenarios using the alternation operator (`|`):

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches("abcdßẞsSSs", "(ss|ß)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Somewhat ironically, this works with all *neutral* and *specific* cultures—i.e., not just `de-DE` and `de`, but even `ja-JP` and `ja`. That said, surprisingly, it will fail with the *invariant* culture, which doesn't evaluate `ß` and `ẞ` as equivalent. As such, if you need to run under the invariant culture—or at least need to use `RegexOptions.CultureInvariant`—then you'll need to use the following:

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches("abßßcdẞẞefsSsSghij", "(ss|ẞ|ß)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
```

Again, this probably isn't the answer you're looking for, and may prove to be a bit complicated to merge with more complicated regular expressions, but it's the best I've been able to come up with given the apparent limitations of Microsoft's RegEx library.